# How can I merge two dictionaries meeting a condition

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

For example:

I have two dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {'machine1': {'operative_system': 'Windows', 'Description':'This is an example'} 'machine2': {'operative_system': 'Ubuntu', 'Description':'This is another example'}}

dict2 = {'machine1': {'Disk1': {'Name_disk':'example'}, 'Disk2': {'Name_disk':'disk2'}}}
```

How can I insert those "disks" into the first dictionary?

The names of the machines are the same...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: did you try with `dict.update`?

Comment: Hello, I tried by using the update method, but seems like for this purpose it does not change the structure of the dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dict.update` to update the existing sub-dictionaries from `dict1`, and wrap in a `try/except` to handle `KeyError` when not in `dict2`

```
for key, value in dict1.items():
    try:
        value.update(dict2[key])
    except KeyError:
        continue
```

Afterwards

```
>>> dict1
{'machine1': {'operative_system': 'Windows',
              'Description': 'This is an example',
              'Disk1': {'Name_disk': 'example'},
              'Disk2': {'Name_disk': 'disk2'}},
 'machine2': {'operative_system': 'Ubuntu',
              'Description': 'This is another example'}}
```

Similarly the following would also work

```
for key, value in dict1.items():
    if key in dict2:
        value.update(dict2[key])
```